# How to fix Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug' in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an android app which is giving "**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.> Job failed, see logs for detail**"

The below is the logcat details.

```
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:there were 14 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

How should I fix this error?

Comment: clean your project from  Android studio -> Build -> clean project

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan That didn't work!

Comment: Do you update any library? show your proguard file too.

Comment: Please post the correct answer if you have managed to solve it.